# Queuing SQL requests PHP

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, queue

Is it possible to queue client requests for accessing database in MySQL. I am trying to do this for concurrency management. MySQL Locks can be used but somehow I am not able to get the desired outcome.

Effectively what I am trying to do is:

- INSERT something in a new row
- SELECT a column from that row
- Store that value in a variable

The issue comes up when two different clients INSERT at the same time, thus variables for both clients store the value of the last INSERT.

I worked the following alternative, but it failed in a few test runs, and the bug is quite evident:

- INSERT
- LOCK Table
- SELECT
- Store
- UNLOCK

Thanks!

Comment: Read up about transactions in MySQL, that's what you need to take care of your problem. Note that you haven't thought of what happens in case your INSERT fails for some reason.

Comment: Let us assume that things work as expected. Ofcourse, your point is valid, but I'd want to tackle that once this is done.

Comment: I really see no reason why not to use the transactions here, everything you need conforms to what transactions were made for. You issue queries that either have to succeed (all of them) or nothing happens (you'd violate data integrity). Everything MySQL offers is available during transactions (like last_insert_id() as suggested before). Consider it before throwing the idea away, it might prove wise in the long run to make your data safe rather than compromise it.

Comment: Oh! I was taking about taking care of INSERT failures. And yes, rightly pointed out, Transactions are the solution, how could I forget!  I can just nest multiple queries as transactions. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Just post your reply as an answer, so I may accept it. On a different note, is it anyways possible to queue SQL accesses in PHP?

Comment: Well, since the problem is nearly solved, I see no reason to re-post the suggestion :) and to answer about SQL and queue in PHP - it depends on what you mean by queue in php - it's a broad topic, you probably should re-post it as a question and give more information on what you mean by queue exactly. In general, everything is possible and there are many ways to achieve the same goal :)

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you have an auto-increment column and want to get its value after inserting a row.  One option is to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)).

If this is not applicable, then please post some more details. What exactly are you trying to do and what queries are being fired?

Comment: The primary key is indeed an AUTO_INCREMENT but the one I am fetching is a TIMESTAMP. So lets say 2 clients simultaneously connect to the server, The first one INSERTS at YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS and second one at YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+1 resulting in session variable storing YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+1 for both sessions. Which is not right.

Comment: Transactions will work as suggested in the comments to your question. Alternately, you can do a `SELECT` after getting the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to enable higher concurrency.